# Postgresql. Функция, возвращающая табличное значение по условию

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE one (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, cond INTEGER);
```

Как написать функцию, возвращающую следующую выборку: если условие есть, то записи, удовлетворяющие этому условию, если его нет, то все записи.
Что-то вроде такого.

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(mycond INTEGER DEFAULT -1) RETURNS one AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF mycond = -1 THEN
        SELECT * FROM one ORDER BY name;
    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM one WHERE cond = mycond ORDER BY name;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE pgplsql;
```

Comment: одним запросом `select * from one where cond = mycond or not exists(select 1 from one where cond = mycond)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f(cond INTEGER) RETURNS SETOF one AS
$$ BEGIN
  IF cond IS NULL THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM one ORDER BY name;
  ELSE
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM one WHERE one.cond = f.cond ORDER BY name;
  END IF;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```